# Dialogflow fulfillment return an empty response

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-analytics-api, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying integrate GA with dialogflow. GA events will be triggered using a fulfilment API, and  responses will come from the dialogflow. This setup is already working, however i'm getting the error below when i send an empty fulfilment response.

Is it possible to send a request to the fulfilment api and not returning a response? Thanks in advance!

```
Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?
at DialogflowConversation.response (/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:237:19)
at DialogflowConversation.serialize (/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:160:129)
at Function.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:173:28)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:19:58)
```

Comment: share your code snipet

Comment: Why do you want to not return a response? Showing us your code, examples of how you want the conversation to sound, or any other information will help us help you.

Comment: FYI, not returning a response (or a silent response) to the user is something Google has noted as a violation of their Google Assistant policy. So if you try to submit this to production, it could be declined by Google. More info on their policies can be found here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#user_experience

Answer (score 1):

In short - no.

Conversations aren't much of a conversation if one half of the conversation doesn't say anything. At the very least, you should respond to indicate you got whatever the user has said, and best practice indicates that the reply should prompt the user.

While there are some tricks you can do to make it sound like there isn't a response, they should be avoided where possible.